# I wont be able to create reference to Bag class: undefined reference to `rosbag::Bag::Bag()

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API) tutorial.
I just want to read the Bag file, but there is linker error: **undefined reference to `rosbag::Bag::Bag()'**

as per tutorial I added all header files (and those all are present in the place where they are supposed to.)
The header files are included successfully. I checked it by :

> cout<< rosbag::rosmode::Read<< endl;

which produce the output :

> 2

Now if I add the following line to source code

> rosbag::Bag bag;

it raising an error:

> undefined reference to  `rosbag::Bag::Bag()'

I have one doubt: Is **rosbag/bag.h** is responsible to create reference of **rosbag::Bag** ??

Further I have seen ros.cpp [here](http://docs.ros.org/diamondback/api/rosbag/html/c++/bag_8cpp_source.html)
But this bag.cpp is not there in my system. (I tried to find it with command - ***locate bag.cpp***)

Also I don't want to use any node, launch, workspace or package of ros to do so, As I want to run this in isolation.
(I am not a very good c++ programmer, forgive me if I am doing any silly mistake. :) )

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265407/i-wont-be-able-to-create-reference-to-bag-class:-undefined-reference-to-%60rosbag::bag::bag()/) by [Hridaynath](https://answers.ros.org/users/30051/hridaynath/) on ROS Answers with karma: 65 on 2017-07-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error you quote is basically a [linking error](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/compiler_linker_errors.html), meaning the linker can't find the library that provides the binary code for a particular symbol you use.

This is not a ROS problem.

In this case you're not linking against the `rosbag` libraries.

You'll need to make sure that you've added `rosbag` to the `find_package(catkin COMPONENTS ..)` (or a regular `find_package(..)`) line in your `CMakeLists.txt`, and that you've added the appropriate `target_link_libraries(..)` that links your executable against the `rosbag` library.

As this is all CMake, you'll want to keep the [CMake Documentation](https://cmake.org/documentation) at hand.

---

Edit:

> @gvdhoorn I made CMakeLists.txt as you suggested: like below:

> ```
> cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
> ```

```
project (tutorial)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED rosbag)
set(SOURCES sampleOne.cpp)
add_executable(test ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(test)
```

Two things here:

1. if you just need `rosbag`, there is no need for `find_package(catkin ..)`, just use `find_package(rosbag REQUIRED)` directly.
2. you have a `target_link_libraries(..)` in there, but you don't actually link your `test` binary against any libraries.

The last point is actually why you're still getting errors.

> both source code and CMakelists.txt is in a directory named "cmake_example".

> Now I ran

> ```
> cmake .
> ```

```
make
```

Please don't use in-source builds with CMake.

> which does not product executable named "test"

> but if I remove first line of source code

> ```
> rosbag::Bag bag;
> ```

> it does create executable named "test", which I can happily execute.

Which makes sense, as you're not actually linking against any of `rosbag`'s libraries.

Try the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
project (tutorial)
find_package(rosbag REQUIRED)
include_directories(${rosbag_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(test sampleOne.cpp)
target_link_libraries(test ${rosbag_LIBRARIES})
```

That will probably work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hridaynath](https://answers.ros.org/users/30051/hridaynath/) on 2017-07-07**:
@gvdhoorn
Thank you very much for your reply.
But I am trying to work with ROS Bag file in Isolation (that is no workspace, no package) usig CPP API.

I can read and manipulate data of Bag file in python without any workspace and package.

**Comment by [Hridaynath](https://answers.ros.org/users/30051/hridaynath/) on 2017-07-07**:
similarly for some task since there is no python library exist, I have to work in cpp.

So my next question is it impossible to work in isolation (that is without workspace and package)?

**Comment by [Hridaynath](https://answers.ros.org/users/30051/hridaynath/) on 2017-07-07**:
I have read some of website but I am clueless.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-07**:
I'm not sure what you are asking exactly. You don't need to have anything installed apart from the `rosbag` package, which can be build using just CMake. That should make both the C++ and the Python APIs available.

**Comment by [Hridaynath](https://answers.ros.org/users/30051/hridaynath/) on 2017-07-10**:
@gvdhoorn
I made CMakeLists.txt as you suggested: like below:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (tutorial)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED rosbag)
set(SOURCES sampleOne.cpp)
add_executable(test ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(test)
```

**Comment by [Hridaynath](https://answers.ros.org/users/30051/hridaynath/) on 2017-07-10**:
I have following code in my "sampleOne.cpp" source file.

```
    rosbag::Bag bag;
    cout<<rosbag::bagmode::Read<<endl;
    cout<<"hello done with ros bag instance"<<endl;
    return 0;
```

**Comment by [Hridaynath](https://answers.ros.org/users/30051/hridaynath/) on 2017-07-10**:
both source code and CMakelists.txt is in a directory named "cmake_example".
Now I ran

```
cmake .
make
```

which does not product executable named "test"
but if I remove first line of source code

```
rosbag::Bag bag;
```

it does create executable named "test", which I can happily execute.

**Comment by [Hridaynath](https://answers.ros.org/users/30051/hridaynath/) on 2017-07-10**:
what I am missing.. I have almost trying for two days now. please help..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-10**:
I would suggest you append to your original question text next time, instead of using a nr of comments. Comments aren't suited for these kind of things.

Use the *edit* button/link to update your original question in that case.

**Comment by [Hridaynath](https://answers.ros.org/users/30051/hridaynath/) on 2017-07-10**:
@gvdhoorn
Thank you very much :)
The issue is solved and I could go ahead now.
(I learned something today.)

> > Use the edit button/link to update your original question in that case

Yes for sure I will keep this in mind next time.

Thank you very much :)